# Which SE site to use for asking a question about learning Hebrew?

Tags: discussion, hebrew, stackexchange

I'm trying to learn Hebrew for an independent study at school, and looking for an online course recommendation. Similar questions seem to have been closed as off-topic on this site, is there a different Stack Exchange site where I could ask them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There have been attempts to start a site for the Hebrew language,  but none have succeeded so far. You have enough reputation to use chat, so  I suggest you ask folks in our chat room, V'dibarta Bam. While it's not usually  a very active room, people are around. (Some monitor the transcript, so even if no one's in the room at the moment, go ahead and say something.)

Answer (score 5):

While there are a whole bunch of Stack Exchange sites devoted to specific languages, Hebrew is not one of them. You can instead try asking on [Language Learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/). According to their [Help Center](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) the following types of questions are on topic:

- Questions about learning or teaching techniques regarding any human
  language, including dead, unspoken and constructed languages.
- Questions regarding definite obstacles faced by anyone learning a
  language.
- Questions regarding specific language learning techniques or
  resources, and their effectiveness in comparison to others.
- Requests seeking books, studies, web sites, or other resources
  supporting the scientific basis for any aspect of language study.
- Questions seeking hard-to-find learning resources for a specific
  language. Be as specific as possible.
- Questions regarding the use of language-learning or teaching software
  or technology (i.e. Duolingo, Anki, etc.) in conjunction with the
  learning/teaching process.

Depending on what exactly your questions are, I think it is very likely they would fit into one or more of these categories.